# Difference of non member inline method and member inline method

Tags: c++

What is the difference between a class-member inline method

```
class A
{
public:
    void method1(void);
..
};
inline void A::method1(void)
{
}
```

and a non-class-member inline method

```
inline void method2(void)
{
}
```

in C++ ?

Comment: One needs an A (or derivative) object, the other doesn't. (and `inline` has nothing to do with that fact).

Comment: In what sense? Normally when somebody talks about an inlined method they mean that the definition is included in the class definition, where the declaration usually appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is pretty much exactly what the difference is when both functions are not inline.

Inlining methods (class-member functions) will be marginally different in that the compiler must ensure that the current object (`this`) is available to the inlined code, but aside from that, there isn't really a significant difference.

Of course, note that `inline` is just a hint and the compiler can not only ignore it, but it can inline methods that have not been declared with the `inline` keyword.

Comment: Does it mean that the additional work by the compiler for inline class members increases the binary size comparatively than for inline non-class functions?